# Salvar um ArrayList<> em uma tabela SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragment, sql-insert

Fala Galera, estou querendo salvar um array list em uma tabela no SQLITE, eu consigo fazer isso? Se sim, como?

Essa é minha tabela:

```
db.execSQL("create table amc (_id integer primary key autoincrement,tipo text not null, resultado float not null,data date not null, id_usuario integer not null, FOREIGN KEY (id_usuario) REFERENCES usuarios (_id);");
```

Quero criar um campo "respostas" para salvar (insert) esse ArrayList: `boolean[] radioButtonValues = new boolean[3];`

Alguém para me ajudar? por favor?

Comment: Se tem `date` isso não é SQLite. Assim como a data, você terá que serializar em *string*  e gravar desata forma.

Comment: Dá uma olhada na nova arquitetura de persistencia de dados do Android, talvez te ajude. Procure usar a Room. Se preicsar eu posto um exemplo ali, abraço!!

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html

Comment: @ArthurCordovaStapassoli teria como você dar um exemplo, por favor?

Comment: Claro, irei montar aqui e postar

Comment: Quando se começa mal a tendência é os problemas multiplicarem-se. Se implementasse a sugestão dada nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217617/2541) só teria de guardar um valor.

Comment: @ramaral mas de qualquer forma terei que utilizar esse método. Pois tenho um listview com 3 RadioButton em cada position da listView. E preciso salvar no banco a seleção de cada RadioButton da ListView.

Comment: Você já não está a guardar as outras informações? É só guardar mais essa(mais um campo na tabela).

Comment: @ramaral sim sim, mas as outras são um campo único, como nome, tipo e contratada. Nesse campo da tabela preciso salvar as respostas.

Comment: Não dá para entender. É melhor fazer outra pergunta com todos os detalhes. O que é uma resposta? Não faz sentido dizer "são um campo único, como nome, tipo e contratada" e "Nesse campo da tabela preciso salvar as respostas".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando a nova arquiterura de persistência do Android, **Room** :
Primeiro é necessário importar as dependencias:

build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}


compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha3"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha3"
```

Resposta.java

```
@Entity
public class Resposta {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "questao")
    private String questao

    @ColumnInfo(name = "is_check")
    private Boolean isCheck;

    // Getters and setters are ignored for brevity,
    // but they're required for Room to work.
}
```

Resposta.java

```
@Dao
public interface RespostaDao {    
    @Query("SELECT * FROM resposta")
    List<User> getAll();

    @Insert
    void insert(Resposta resposta);

    @Delete
    void delete(Resposta resposta);
}
```

AppDatabase.java

```
@Database(entities = {Resposta.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract RespostaDao respostaDao();
}
```

Activity.java

```
...
    AppDatabase db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(),
    AppDatabase.class, "database-name").build();

    List<Resposta> respostas = metodoQuePovoaSuaLista();
    for(Resposta r : respostas){
        db.respostaDao().insert(r);
    }
...
```

Qualquer dúvida conversamos, mas a documentação esta bem legal [Aqui](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html)