# Quando rolo minha listView perco os checkboxes marcados

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

Esse é um código do meu adapter, nele eu tenho um textview e 4 chekboxes. O problema é que eu acredito que tenho que salvar o status dos meus checkboxes, para não perder os dados dele, porque quando eu rolo minha list view meus checkboxes desmarcam sozinhos.

```
public class ListaFuncionarioAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
/*
   private Activity activity;
    private List<MeuItem> itens;

    public ListaFuncionarioAdapter(Activity activity, List<MeuItem> itens){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.itens = itens;
    }
*/
    private List<MeuItem> itens;

    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    CheckBox chkSalManha, chkDoceManha, chkSalTarde, chkDoceTarde;
    private Context context;

    private List<QtdePaes> listQtdePaes = new ArrayList<QtdePaes>();
    private ArrayAdapter<QtdePaes> arrayAdapterQtdePaes;
    QtdePaes qtdePaesSelecionado;
    private List<Funcionario> listFuncionario;

    final QtdePaes qtdePaes = new QtdePaes();

    int salmanha = 0;
    int saltarde = 0;
    int docemanha = 0;
    int docetarde = 0;

    public ListaFuncionarioAdapter(Context context, List<Funcionario> listFuncionario) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listFuncionario = listFuncionario;
    }



    private void inicializarFirebase() {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
       // firebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();

        //DatabaseReference novaReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
       // novaReference = databaseReference.child("minh");

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listFuncionario.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listFuncionario.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }




    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View v= View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_funcionario, null);

        chkSalManha = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.chkSalManha);
        chkDoceManha = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.chkDoceManha);
        chkSalTarde = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.chkSalTarde);
        chkDoceTarde = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.chkDoceTarde);
        TextView txtNome = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);

        inicializarFirebase();
        txtNome.setText(String.valueOf(listFuncionario.get(position).getNome()));

        //MeuItem item = itens.get(position);

        //chkSalManha.setTag(item);
        //chkSalManha.setChecked(item.foiMarcado());
        v.setTag(listFuncionario.get(position).getUid());



        chkSalManha.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){
                    salmanha += 1;
                    String estado = (String) chkSalManha.getTag();

                   // qtdePaes.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalManha(salmanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceManha(docemanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalTarde(saltarde);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceTarde(docetarde);
                    //databaseReference.child("QtdePaes").child(qtdePaes.getUid()).setValue(qtdePaes);
                    databaseReference.child("QtdePaes").child("6fd2aede-e00f-48d8-b6cb-f1498e23e8e8").setValue(qtdePaes);


                }
                if(!isChecked)
                {

                    salmanha -= 1;
                    //qtdePaes.setUid(qtdePaesSelecionado.getUid());
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalManha(salmanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceManha(docemanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalTarde(saltarde);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceTarde(docetarde);
                    databaseReference.child("QtdePaes").child("6fd2aede-e00f-48d8-b6cb-f1498e23e8e8").setValue(qtdePaes);


                }
            }
        });


        chkSalTarde.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){
                    saltarde += 1;

                    //qtdePaes.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalTarde(salmanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceManha(docemanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalTarde(saltarde);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceTarde(docetarde);
                    //databaseReference.child("QtdePaes").child(qtdePaes.getUid()).setValue(qtdePaes);
                    databaseReference.child("QtdePaes").child("6fd2aede-e00f-48d8-b6cb-f1498e23e8e8").setValue(qtdePaes);

                }
                if(!isChecked)
                {

                    saltarde -= 1;
                    //qtdePaes.setUid(qtdePaesSelecionado.getUid());
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalTarde(salmanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceManha(docemanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalTarde(saltarde);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceTarde(docetarde);
                    databaseReference.child("QtdePaes").child("6fd2aede-e00f-48d8-b6cb-f1498e23e8e8").setValue(qtdePaes);


                }
            }
        });

        chkDoceManha.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){

                    docemanha += 1;

                    //qtdePaes.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalTarde(salmanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceManha(docemanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalTarde(saltarde);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceTarde(docetarde);
                    //databaseReference.child("QtdePaes").child(qtdePaes.getUid()).setValue(qtdePaes);
                    databaseReference.child("QtdePaes").child("6fd2aede-e00f-48d8-b6cb-f1498e23e8e8").setValue(qtdePaes);

                }
                if(!isChecked)
                {

                    docemanha -= 1;
                    //qtdePaes.setUid(qtdePaesSelecionado.getUid());
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalTarde(salmanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceManha(docemanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalTarde(saltarde);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceTarde(docetarde);
                    databaseReference.child("QtdePaes").child("6fd2aede-e00f-48d8-b6cb-f1498e23e8e8").setValue(qtdePaes);


                }
            }
        });

        chkDoceTarde.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){
                    docetarde += 1;

                   // qtdePaes.setUid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalTarde(salmanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceManha(docemanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalTarde(saltarde);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceTarde(docetarde);
                    //databaseReference.child("QtdePaes").child(qtdePaes.getUid()).setValue(qtdePaes);
                    databaseReference.child("QtdePaes").child("6fd2aede-e00f-48d8-b6cb-f1498e23e8e8").setValue(qtdePaes);


                }
                if(!isChecked)
                {

                    docetarde -= 1;
                    //qtdePaes.setUid(qtdePaesSelecionado.getUid());
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalTarde(salmanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceManha(docemanha);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeSalTarde(saltarde);
                    qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceTarde(docetarde);
                    databaseReference.child("QtdePaes").child("6fd2aede-e00f-48d8-b6cb-f1498e23e8e8").setValue(qtdePaes);


                }
            }
        });



        return v;

    }


}
```

Comment: Por que esse monte código `qtdePaes.setALGMACOISA` repetido tanto nos ifs quanto nos else's? Você pode mover esses blocos para depois do if-else e deixar dentro deles só o que realmente é diferente entre eles.

Comment: Eu modifiquei o meu projeto, estava muito bagunçado, @MárcioOliveira. Segui suas recomendações. ficou menos código, e funcionando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada vez que a ListView necessita de renderizar um item/linha chama o método `getView()` do *adapter*.

Na implementação desse método é feito o *inflate* de um novo *layout* e é atribuído às suas views os respectivos valores.

Este processo é repetido enquanto houver itens na lista ou a altura da ListView ficar preenchida.

Quando é feito *scroll*, novos *layouts* são "inflados" para as posições inferiores e os das posições superiores são descartados.

O processo é idêntico quando o *scroll* é feito em sentido contrário.

Se entretanto tiver marcado qualquer um dos CheckBox, essa marcação será perdida quando o respectivo *layout*/item/linha for descartado em consequência do *scroll*.

Assim, a solução passa por guardar o estado dos *checbox's* no objecto que é usado para preencher a ListView e atribuí-lo ao CheckBox da mesma forma que são atribuídos os valores às outra *views*. Veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217617/2541) um exemplo.

**Nota:** Para tornar o processo de criação de novos *layouts* mais eficiente considere usar o padrão [View holder](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) ou uma [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html).

Comment: esse comportamento que você descreveu **"Quando é feito scroll, novos layouts são "inflados" para as posições inferiores e os das posições superiores são descartados."** não se refere a RecyclerView? Pelo o que eu me lembro, a ListView carrega todos. Desculpe se estiver errado.

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida Julgo que está enganado. Tanto a ListView como a RecyclerView apenas carregam(é chamado o método do adapter `getView()`/`onBindViewHolder()` para) os itens visíveis a cada momento.

Answer (score 0):

O problema a ultima condição não tem um `else`, então isso acaba "entrelaçando" os itens.

Em vez de colocar:

```
if(isChecked){
// conteúdo
}
if(!isChecked){
// conteúdo
}
```

Coloque:

```
if(isChecked){
// conteúdo
}else{
// conteúdo
}
```

Isso garantirá que os `CheckBox`s não sejam desmarcados caso estejam marcados.

Comment: Obrigado, amigo, mas definitivamente o problema maior é a questao de eu perder os dados do listView

Comment: @LucianoPedrosa se você fizer desta forma, não vão ser mais desmarcados.

Comment: Não vejo diferença nenhuma, em termos de resultado final, entre os dois códigos.

Comment: No entanto a forma tradicional é fazer com `if/else`.

Comment: @ramaral pelo menos comigo, sempre que deixei um if "solto" em um custom adapter, sempre perdeu conteúdo por causa da reciclagem de views. Este é meu palpite em relação a perca de checkbox, pois a última condição não se conclui com um else. Parece a coisa mais idiota do mundo.

Comment: @ramaral não encherei nada no código que faça perder o resultado além disso. Você conseguiu enchergar?

Comment: Sim, eu entendo onde quer chegar. No entanto `else` é o mesmo que testar a negação do teste. Repare também que esses `if` estão no `onCheckedChanged()` do listener e não no `getView()` do adapter.

Comment: @ramaral entendi o que quiz dizer. O certo então seria criar as condições dentro do `getView` mas sem estar dentro do `setOnCheckedChangeListener` para resolver o problema. Vamos esperar um feedback.

Comment: Em parte, no `setOnCheckedChangeListener` devem estar as condições se houver algo a alterar caso o CheckBox seja seleccionado/desseleccionado. Lá também deve ser guardado o estado do CheckBox no objecto da lista. No `getView()` deve-se verificar qual o estado guardado e "setar" o CheckBox de acordo.

Comment: @ramaral, segui sua sugestão, eu modifiquei o projeto e agora estou usando o layout recyclerview, agora não perco mais minhas informações do checkbox. Meu código estava muito bagunçado. Corrigi muita coisa, agora estou usando mais boas práticas de programação.

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que a quantidade de itens do seu ListView não irá variar de tamanho, então para simplificar, você pode criar um array booleano de 2 dimensões estático no seu adapter.

Ex:

```
private static boolean [][] checkBoxStates; // a primeira dimensão é a quantidade de itens da sua lista, a segunda dimensão, a quantidade de checkboxes por item
```

Inicializar o array no construtor do adapter:

```
public ListaFuncionarioAdapter(Context context, List<Funcionario> listFuncionario) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listFuncionario = listFuncionario;
    checkBoxStates = new  boolean [listFuncionario.size()][];
    // supondo que o status inicial de todas as check boxes é desmarcado
    for(int i = 0; i < listFuncionario.size(); i++)
        checkBoxStates[i] = new boolean[]{false, false, false, false};
    }

}
```

Guardando/recuperando o estado dos checks:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  ...
  // após associar os checkboxes com o findviewById
  chkSalManha.setChecked(checkBoxStates[position][0]);
  chkDoceManha.setChecked(checkBoxStates[position][1]);
  chkSalTarde.setChecked(checkBoxStates[position][2]);
  chkDoceTarde.setChecked(checkBoxStates[position][3]);

  ...
  // Guardando o estado nos listeners:
  chkSalManha.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                checkBoxStates[position][0] = isChecked;
                ...

            }


  chkDoceManha.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                checkBoxStates[position][1] = isChecked;
                ...

            }

  chkSalTarde.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                checkBoxStates[position][2] = isChecked;
                ...

            }

  chkDoceTarde.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                checkBoxStates[position][3] = isChecked;
                ...

            }
  ...

 }
```

E como já sugerido, você pode mudar o código dos if-else dos seus listeners dessa forma:

```
 chkSalManha.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            checkBoxStates[position][1] = isChecked;

            if(isChecked)
                salmanha++;
            else
                salmanha--;
            }

            qtdePaes.setQtdeSalManha(salmanha);
            qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceManha(docemanha);
            qtdePaes.setQtdeSalTarde(saltarde);
            qtdePaes.setQtdeDoceTarde(docetarde);
            databaseReference.child("QtdePaes").child("6fd2aede-e00f-48d8-b6cb-f1498e23e8e8").setValue(qtdePaes);
        }
    });
```